# VB.NET overload () operator

Tags: vb.net, brackets

I am new to VB.NET and search for a method to copy the behaviour of a DataRow for example.
In VB.NET I can write something like this:

```
Dim table As New DataTable
'assume the table gets initialized
table.Rows(0)("a value") = "another value"
```

Now how can I access a member of my class with brackets? I thought i could overload the () Operator but this seems not to be the answer.

Comment: Indexer? [How to create an indexer property in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311323)

Comment: `()` is not an operator.  it is how to access a collection of things.  the second set on your example is the cells or items collection for `Rows(0)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an overload operator, this known as a [default property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/371ww4fs(v=vs.90).aspx).

> *"A class, structure, or interface can designate at most one of its properties as the default property, provided that property takes at least one parameter. If code makes a reference to a class or structure without specifying a member, Visual Basic resolves that reference to the default property." - MSDN -*

Both the `DataRowCollection` class and the `DataRow` class have a default property named `Item`.

```
            |       |
table.Rows.Item(0).Item("a value") = "another value"
```

This allows you to write the code without specifying the `Item` members:

```
table.Rows(0)("a value") = "another value"
```

Here's a simple example of a custom class with a default property:

```
Public Class Foo

    Default Public Property Test(index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return Me.items(index)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.items(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly items As String() = New String(2) {"a", "b", "c"}

End Class
```

```
Dim f As New Foo()
Dim a As String = f(0)

f(0) = "A"
```

Given the example above, you can use the default property of the string class to get a character at specified position.

```
f(0) = "abc"
Dim c As Char = f(0)(1) '<- "b" | f.Test(0).Chars(1)
```